# How to inject an external factory provider in angular config?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to inject a factory provider from another js file but it can't locate the provider. If this can't be done, what is the better way?

demo.config.js

```
function configState($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider, demoProvider) {

    // Optimize load start with remove binding information inside the DOM element
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);

    // Set default state
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $stateProvider

        // Dashboard - Main page
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
            }
        })
}

angular
    .module('demoApp')
    .config(configState)
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
```

demo.provider.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('demoApp')
        .provider('demo', function() {
            return {
                $get: function() { 
                    return {
                        title: "Starcraft"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

})();
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Be precise. Paste any error message you might get. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe for how to correctly define a provider.

Comment: Respect from Aiur!!))

Comment: @JBNizet This is the error I'm getting: 
`Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/modulerr?p0=ivrwebapp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.20%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DdemoProvider%0AS%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A417%0Acb%2Fp.%24injector%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A7%0Ad%40http%3A%2F`

Comment: Use angular.js instead of angular.min.js to have readable error messages. The minified file is for production, not development. My guess is that you simply forgot to add a <script> in your html for demo.provider.js.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet for the tip. It helped me figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I always put my own provider to controllers. Like in my directive

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('yourMod').directive('yourViewPage', yourViewPage);


    angular.module('yourMod').controller('YourViewPageCtrl', YourViewPageCtrl);


    function YourViewPageCtrl(YourProvider) {
        //your code!!!
        // Example YourProvider.getSomeThing();
        console.log('My life for Aiur!!!');
    }

})();
```